# How to copy multiple files in multiple folders using Python

Tags: python, shutil

I have multiple files in one folder (1_ppt.csv, 2_ppt.csv, 3_ppt.csv,...). I have their corresponding empty folders as (SIM1, SIM2, SIM3,...). I want to copy the 1_ppt.csv to SIM1 folder, 2_ppt.csv to SIM2 folder,...so on. I tried it using cmd command, it works; however, it requires the file and folder names to be same, so its not useful. I will really appreciate if I can get a python solution to this.

Used these cmd commands so far.

```
[for %i in (*) do mkdir "%~ni"]
[for %i in (*) do move "%i" "%~ni"]
```

Comment: You shouldn't need python for [this](https://ss64.com/nt/for_l.html).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that the file tree looks like this:

```
|--PPTs
|   |--1_ppt.csv
|   |--2_ppt.csv
|   .
|   .
|   |--n_ppt.csv
|--SIM1
|--SIM2
.
.
|--SIMN
|--script.py
```

You can do the following:

```
from pathlib import Path
import shutil

base_path = Path.cwd()
ppt_path = base_path.joinpath('PPTs')
for ppt in ppt_path.iterdir():
    ppt_num = ppt.name.split('_')[0]
    out_path = base_path.joinpath(f'SIM{ppt_num}', ppt.name) # e.g. SIM1/ppt_1.csv
    shutil.copy(ppt, out_path)
```

You can also create directories on the fly by modifying the for loop:

```
for ppt in ppt_path.iterdir():
    ppt_num = ppt.name.split('_')[0]
    out_folder = base_path.joinpath(f'SIM{ppt_num}')
    # Add this line
    out_folder.mkdir(exist_ok=True)
    out_path = out_folder.joinpath(ppt.name) # e.g. SIM1/ppt_1.csv
    shutil.copy(ppt, out_path)
```

Comment: Thanks for sharing the code adrianp. It was really helpful. Works perfectly fine.

Answer (score 1):

```
import os
import shutil
src=""
src_files = os.listdir(src)
i=0
for file_name in src_files:
   full_file_name = os.path.join(src, file_name)
   if os.path.isfile(full_file_name)& full_file_name.endswith("_ppt.csv"):
     i+=1
     dirName="SIM"+str(i)
     try:
     # Create target Directory
       os.mkdir(dirName)
     except FileExistsError:

    if not os.path.exists(dirName):
       os.mkdir(dirName)  

    shutil.copy(full_file_name, dirName)
```

Put this python file into where you want your SIM folders to go and put the src of where your one folder is.